# Lambda v Cron for ebs snapshot rotation for backup/DR

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

What's the upside for using AWS Lambda over boto3 driven by cron for creating snapshots for backup and disaster recovery?

My goal is to have snapshots going back 30 days or so with one snapshot every 6 months pushed on to glacier.  This gives me a fast restoration on corruption or a botched upgrade with cheap long term storage for services like jenkins.  I've got boto3 based scripts for create-snap/restore-to-snap/mount-snap).

**Lamda**

- IAM policies linked to just that one action

**Cron**

- instance role based IAM policies leak to the instance (which isn't idea for a jenkins server for example).
- **might** be easier to use my python module which can be tested via mocks etc.

So, Lambda seems slightly more complex but if terraform manages it, then I should be able to combine my python scripts with unit testing and then push them to lambda for CloudWatch to execute.

Are there wins or costs that I'm missing?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a question about product recommendation? Because those get outdated pretty quickly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS lambda allows for triggering from several sources including the storage remaining in your database and even cron triggers. You can even cascade scripts from each other meaning you can run several small easy to maintain scripts instead of one large orchestrated script. You also get the ease of keeping your maintenance right next to your resources making it a single point of maintenance in AWS.

If you put your script on another server you're also paying for idle time in the server instead of only when your maintenance needs to run. You also open yourself to needing to maintain that other server as well(which depending may just be restarts to update os). Adding maintenance rui something you can get in house without maintenance seems like a pretty big con to me.

---

After further digging into Lambda beyond the use cases I've just seen recently I decided to through together a list of pros and cons more aimed towards maintenance than actual code execution since that's REALLY where the differences come out:

## AWS Lambda

### Pros

- Single place for maintenance
- No remote access concerns
- Smaller security footprint
- Cloud Watch triggers, of which Cron is but just one of the triggers you can use
- No server costs, only pay when you use compute time
- Free tier access means if your maintenance doesn't take long, you might not actually end up paying for it
- Adaptability in choice of language as time goes on. You can migrate to many other languages for maintenance by team members
- Local testing is easy to setup as Lambda isn't to hard to emulate locally

### Cons

- Idle timing is something you get charged for, so be careful of async requests and low priority. A sweet spot seems to exist around the 1024 MB memory option where priority outweighs time and the costs begin to level out for heavy async scripts
- Setup
- Rigid environment
- Confusing environment at first. Things get nested in odd ways before being exposed through the context object

## Cron on a Server

### Pros

- Familiar to any Sysadmin
- Easy to setup
- More granular control
- No competing for compute resources or priority

### Cons

- Manual maintenance setup
- OS Maintenance
- You pay for idle time
- lots of idle resources
- requires a bit of specialty beyond just being a programmer

The maintenance wins and the fact that you don't have to know anything about a system or how it works for maintaining it in the future is what makes Lambda so enticing for so many people. You don't have to worry about 'Did I set permissions right' or 'Is the trigger I had to setup manually correct' or 'Did this subsystem change between OS updates'. Lambda is a defined, controlled execution and setup space that takes the maintenance out of it for you. That's a pretty big win and why many development groups are moving to the `DevOps` model. No sys admins and no sys problems.

Comment: You would use Boto in an AWS Lambda function (written in Python) if you were doing any interaction with the AWS API, such as triggering EBS snapshots... Why are you trying to compare an SDK to a "serverless" cloud compute environment? Why are you saying Lambda's support by AWS is a big consideration? Boto is the official AWS SDK for Python, and is supported by AWS accordingly. The question is about comparing Cron jobs on a server to scheduled AWS Lambda functions.

Comment: My guess is that https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/ops-automator/architecture.html might be the best option - less code for me more functions for "free"

Comment: You could yes, but it brings in dynamodb costs and has a lot of extra that you might not need. Still having predefined tasks for some of this could be really helpful

Comment: if managing snapshots was my only ops automation use then perhaps it wouldn't be worth it, however if I use for a variety of other tasks, then the costs might be warranted.  Thanks for the answer to my question.